# ASP.NET/Javascript error. Sporadically occurs, 'length is null or not an object'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-config, null

This one has me perplexed. I have a web app that does many functions, but the part that it is bombing out is when doing a Search function which calls a webservice and returns results back from DB2.

The odd thing, is the error doesn't always occur and only seems to occur when accessing my web app through a vip(which is on a load balancer, round-robin on 2 IIS Servers). The error doesn't come up when accessing the web app when using the direct URL for one of the servers.

Which leads me to believe, something with my web.config?

Also I searched my javascript code, and I don't use Length anywhere.

Please help, i've been banging my head against the wall on this.

**UPDATED with code(I included the neccessary code below, omitted the rest):**

//Javascript***

function ValidateSearch() {

```
if (Page_ClientValidate("TransSearch") == true) {              
                ShowWait();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
```

}

function ShowWait() {

```
    target = document.getElementById('progress');
    document.body.appendChild(target);
    spinner.spin(target);
//This calls spinner.js from github
```

}

function searchComplete() {

```
//clear previous search textboxes
document.getElementById('<%# txtEmail.ClientID %>').value = "";
    document.getElementById('<%# txtPhone.ClientID %>').value = "";

spinner.stop();
```

}

//Markup***

```
    <div class="searchlabel">
    <label>Email Address</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="EmailReq"  
                ControlToValidate="txtEmail"  ValidationGroup="TransSearch"
            Display="None"  
            ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Email is required." />  
        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="EmailReqE"  
            TargetControlID="EmailReq"  
            HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight"  />
</div>
<div class="searchlabel">
        <label>Phone</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="PhnReq"  
                ControlToValidate="txtPhone"  ValidationGroup="TransSearch"
                Display="None"  
                ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Phone is required." />  
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="PhnReqE"  
                TargetControlID="PhnReq"  
                HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" /> 
    </div> 
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="90px" OnClientClick="return ValidateSearch();" OnClick="Search_Click" />
```

//Codebehind***

public void Search_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
//passes search text to webservice
//fills gridview with returned data
//lastly calls javascript function to stop spinner
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "searchComplete", "<script type='text/javascript'>searchComplete();</script>", false);
```

}

Comment: Is it occurs in same place or in different places?

Comment: Same place everytime. It just doesn't occur all of the time.

Comment: Here are the steps...
1) Search button is clicked
2) OnClientClick fires javascript which checks Page_ClientValidate, returns true and kicks off spinner.spin (wait gif)
3) Then OnClick fires to codehehind where webservice makes call, and returns data back
4) Calls javascript function to stop spinner
and thats it.

When it errors out, the results are returned, but the spinner is still spinning, with a javascript error "Length is null or not an object"

Comment: I added the code of what path clicking the search button does. Left out any unneccessary code.

Comment: Thats the thing, I'm not 100% sure where the error is occuring. I know its not in the codebehind, because I error trap. It happening before searchComplete() is called, because my textboxes don't clear, and the spinner doesn't stop.  But like i said, it doesn't happen every time and only in Production, which makes its difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your javascript function is not getting the textbox you are providing it with.

```
document.getElementById('<%# txtEmail.ClientID %>').value
```

Check the value using:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%# txtEmail.ClientID %>').value )
```

if it is returning value. This maybe the reason your spinner.stop(); is not working.

Use alert to see if it is entering your function. I use it every time I am stuck in javascript . It helps me to find after which line the function is giving error.

Comment: I see your point, but i still go back to my original question. If its bombing out when trying to get textbox value, wouldn't it bomb out every single time?  As i said before, this same code works flawlessly when running locally and on Dev server.  But on Production (same code) is bombs out every so often.

Comment: I'm going to call this one answered.  But i think running through the vip (load balancer) is causing these issues, whether it be incorrect web.config, or something else.  I've chosen to forget about the vip(load balancer) and just use direct server ip.

Comment: i cant tell you by the piece of code you have provided here, that what exactly is the problem..i thought this could possibly be the issue. But, "not an object" is caused when your function do not find the control you have sent it. so the issue here may be is what is causing the control to (not) load.

Comment: jakk220: this may solve your problem try to check the textbox if it is empty                                    if(document.getElementById('<%# txtEmail.ClientID %>').value) != "";    { //Then your code}  it will be better if you check it for both textbox email and phone.